How to update an ImageButton's Visability based on a Database Call
I'm newish to android development so I believe I'm having a fundamental misunderstanding of how I should approach this problem.
Essentially, I have an Image Button that I want to toggle its visibility based on a database call. It doesn't compile because it keeps saying  If a binding adapter provides the setter, check that the adapter is annotated correctly and that the parameter type matches. on the View Model Portion of the BindingAdapter.
Note: Only including portions that pertain
My XML:
    <variable
            name="serial"
            type="com.android.test.persistence.Item.Item" />
        <variable
            name="viewmodel"
            type="com.android.test.viewmodel.cart.CartPageViewModel" />
<ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/cart_has_items_icon"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:contentDescription="@string/cart_has_items_icon"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/item_30"
            android:visibility="@{viewmodel.hasItem ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
            app:viewmodel="@{viewmodel}"
            app:serial="@{item}"/>

In My  ViewModel:
    private Boolean hasSpecificItem;
    public boolean updateCartIfSpecificItemPresent(Item item){
           // this is just a db call that returns true or false if condition is met
            return dbcall(item).stream().anyMatch(item -> item().equals(item));
        }
        @Bindable
        public Boolean getHasItem() {
            return this.hasFrustratedLoads;
        }
        public void setHasItem(Item item) {
            this.hasSpecificItem = updateCartIfSpecificItemPresent(serial);
            notifyPropertyChanged(BR.hasItem);
        }

My BindingAdapter:
    @BindingAdapter(value={"viewModel", "item"}, requireAll = true)
public static void setHasItem(CartPageViewModel viewModel, Item item) {
    viewModel.updateCartIfSpecificItemPresent(item);
}

Am I going about this the right way? Any help/pointers is greatly appreciated!
